# How can I fix this memory leak in my NodeJS file manipulation application?

Tags: node.js, api, file, express, io

My applications purpose at this stage is to take an input file and add common password replacements to a given password phrase. The catch is it performs this operation on a potentially large file (1+GB of text), one password per line, and then appends the resulting list of potential replacements back to the same input file through a `writeStream`.

So, for example, an input of 5_passwords.txt which contains:

```
password
hello
chicken
bye
bobthebuilder
```

could result in a file like this:

```
...
p@s$w0rd
h3ll0
ch1ck3n
8y3
b0bth3bu11d34
...
```

When a large file is used, the memory usage also increases, but it should stay the same from my understanding. The following is the actual console output logs for `Memory use: ${Math.round(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024 * 100 / 100)}MB`

**Memory use at the start:**  `Memory use: 20MB`  (Around what the app should be using)

**Memory use after 10 seconds:** `Memory use: 476MB`  (Uh oh...)

**Memory use after 30 seconds:** `Memory use: 1159MB`  (LIKE WOAH)

The following is my relevant code:

```
const commonReplacesments = {
    a : [
        '4',
        '@'
    ],
    b : [
        '8'
    ],
    c : [
        '(',
        '{',
        '[',
        '<'
    ],
    e : [
        '3'
    ],
    g : [
        '6',
        '9'
    ],
    i : [
        '1',
        '!',
        '|'
    ],
    l : [
        '1',
        '|',
        '7'
    ],
    o : [
        '0'
    ],
    p : [
        '9'
    ],
    r : [
        '4'
    ],
    s : [
        '$',
        '5'
    ],
    t : [
        '+',
        '7'
    ],
    x : [
        '%'
    ],
    z : [
        '2'
    ]
}

// word ... is the word to generate *some* possible manipulations on using the commonreplacements above
const replaceWord = async (word) => {
    let wordsWithReplacements = []
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        let currentWord = word
        if (currentWord[i] in commonReplacesments) {
            for (let j = 0; j < commonReplacesments[currentWord[i]].length; j++) {
                let replacer = new RegExp(currentWord[i], 'g')
                currentWord = currentWord.replace(replacer, commonReplacesments[currentWord[i][j])
                wordsWithReplacements.push(currentWord)

                // Reset word
                currentWord = word

                console.log(
                    `[${Date.now()}] Memory use: ${Math.round(
                        process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024 * 100 / 100
                    )}MB`
                )
            }
        }
    }

    return wordsWithReplacements
}

// passFile ... Is the absolute file path to the password file being manipulated.
const addCommonReplacements = async (passFile) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(passFile)

    console.log('Adding common replacements to existing phrases in password list...')

    try {
        await util.promisify(stream.pipeline)(async function*() {
            for await (const password of readStream) {
                yield `${await (await replaceWord(`${password}`)).join('\n')}`
            }
        }, fs.createWriteStream(passFile, { flags: 'a' }))
    } catch (err) {
        Promise.reject(`ERROR: Failed to write common replacements to file...${err}`)
    }
}
```

If anyone can please provide some insight to help me solve this problem I would greatly appreciate it :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to launch your code but I've come up with this simplified version and it looks like it's working well (even though there are some `undefined` values in the result but that is related to the replace function which I didn't really look into). You can leverage Node.js's internal package [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) which parses line from a stream for you.

```
const addCommonReplacements = async passFile => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(passFile)
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('out.txt')

    var rl = readline.createInterface(readStream, writeStream)

    rl.on('line', function (password) {
        writeStream.write(`${replaceWord(password)}\n`)
    });
}
```

Also, I don't think it is a good idea to read from and write to the same file!

PS. I run the script on the file with 65536 lines with the max memory used 27MB.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thank you for your post! I am wondering, however, why do you not think its a good idea to read from and write to the same file?

Comment: This code does not actually write anything. Also just as a note the `replaceWord` function is async and returns a **list** of possible replacements so you can't just write the list directly to the `writeStream`.

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure the issue lies in the `replaceWord` function, not the `addCommonReplacements` function since when I run the code without doing the replacements and simply reading from the file and appending the unmodified content back to the write stream it has no memory leak.